# How to test a React app in mobile dimensions?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, breakpoints, cypress, react-testing-library

I'm building a React app and I'm testing it with Cypress and React Testing library.

I was wondering: How can I test the app "on mobile". Meaning how can I write tests for the app that run if the window size is below the breakpoint? I couldn't find anything about that in the respective packages documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check this page - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport.html

You can control the size and orientation of the screen for your application. There are also preset dimensions available already for various devices,

**Preset        width      height**

- macbook-15   1440    900
- macbook-13   1280    800
- macbook-11   1366    768
- ipad-2   768 1024
- ipad-mini    768 1024
- iphone-6+    414 736
- iphone-6 375 667
- iphone-5 320 568
- iphone-4 320 480
- iphone-3 320 480

Just need to pass `cy.viewport('iphone-6')`  which will set the viewport to 375px x 667px. Hope this helps.